# How to just change the TimeZone with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, java-8

I want to convert date from this format to **Tue Sep 08 14:27:00 IST 2015** to **2015-09-08T14:27:00-0500** how to do this with SimpleDateFormat?

I tried like this way

```
Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
ft.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern"));
ft.format(cl.getTime());
```

the above code giving output **2015-09-08T04:57:00-0400** but I want to change only timezone and it should be **-0500**

How could I do this?

Comment: This is tagged with java-8, any reason you don't use the new time api?

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
ft.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-5"))
```

sample:

```
Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

ft.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern"));
System.out.println(ft.format(cl.getTime()));

ft.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-5"));
System.out.println(ft.format(cl.getTime()));
```

produces:

```
2016-03-23T16:39:22-0400
2016-03-23T15:39:22-0500
```

source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleDateFormat` uses a `Calendar` instance to work with `Dates`. If you change the timezone, the timezone of this `Calendar` instance is changed. If you really want to change only the output - in your case the timezone, without changing the Time (i do not know why you want to do this, but i assume you have a reason), you could do something like this:

```
Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern");//TimeZone.getDefault(); 
int offset = tz.getRawOffset();
String offsetStr = ((offset < 0) ? "-" : "+") + String.format("%02d%02d", 
        Math.abs(offset / 3600000), (offset / 60000) % 60);
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'" + offsetStr+"'");
String dt = ft.format(cl.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working fine for me

```
Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of(ZoneId.SHORT_IDS.get("EST"));
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'"+offset.getId()+"'");
formatter.format(cl.getTime());
```